# Android: How to keep switch and label together

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, view

I am trying to keep a switch and its label together.

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="This is a label" />
```

The problem I am having is that the switch and its label separate to opposite sides of the screen. I know I can change android:layout_width ="wrap_content" but I am trying to create a white background (#FFFFFF) that is the height of the content and the width of the screen. I also know I could put the switch in a RelativeLayout with this background, but I feel like that would be creating an extra unnecessary view. Is there anyway to stop the switch's label from separating from the switch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have written an [article](http://www.steventrigg.com/building-a-custom-toggle-button-create-an-alarm-clock-in-android-tutorial-part-3/) about this exact problem and my own [solution](https://github.com/steventrigg/AlarmClock/blob/master/AlarmClock/src/com/trigg/alarmclock/CustomSwitch.java).

This will give you a single component, with a switch (or checkbox based on API version) on the right and it's label on the left. Just like in the preferences screen. A touch on the label and surrounding layout will change the state of the switch.

You can modify and rearrange the switch however you like to achieve your desired view.